# MS Access SQL that shows full list even if other list does not include

Tags: sql, ms-access, filtering

I am trying to write a query that makes a list that says show how much of each item is left in the inventory on a certain day.

I have the following tables:

tblTypes

```
 - Types
```

tblRooms

```
 - Room
 - Type
```

tblDates

```
 - Date
 - Type
```

I have the following queries:

```
--qryRoomInventory--
SELECT 
    tblTypes.Type, Count(tblRooms.Type) AS Inventory
FROM 
    tblTypes 
INNER JOIN 
    tblRooms ON tblTypes.Type = tblRooms.Type
GROUP BY 
    tblTypes.Type;

--qryBooked--
SELECT 
    tblDates.Type, tblDates.Date, Count(tblDates.Type) AS Booked, 
    [Inventory]-[Booked] AS Opened
FROM 
    (tblTypes 
INNER JOIN 
    tblDates ON tblTypes.Type = tblDates.Type) 
INNER JOIN 
    qryRoomInventory ON tblTypes.Type = qryRoomInventory.Type
GROUP BY 
    tblDates.Type, tblDates.Date, qryRoomInventory.Inventory
HAVING 
    (((tblDates.Date) = Date()));
```

The problem is that it is only showing the types that are in the `tblDates` but cutting out the rest of them. How do I get it to show the whole list of types and just assume there were 0 booked if it is not on the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a `LEFT JOIN` for this.  For instance, your first query would be:

```
SELECT tblTypes.Type, Count(tblRooms.Type) AS Inventory
FROM tblTypes LEFT JOIN
     tblRooms
     ON tblTypes.Type = tblRooms.Type
GROUP BY tblTypes.Type;
```

If you have multiple `INNER JOIN`s (such as the second query), then you should replace all of them with `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: LEFT JOIN fixed it. Thank you.